# How can I make an editable DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

Basically I have the following in my MainWindow:

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> Environment { get; set; }
```

and I want to bind it to a datagrid in such a way that I can edit the data grid and have `Environment` be updated. Specifically, I want to be able to add new rows, delete rows, and edit individual cells. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In xaml you can write:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SomeString">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeString}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SomeInt>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeInt}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In code behind make:
Data class "DataClass" with fields SomeString and SomeInt
"ViewModel" class, inherits INotifyPropertyChanged and use "DataClass"
Write:

```
 ObservableCollection<ViewModel> Environment
```

and instatiate it with pairs of SomeString and SomeInt

Set datacontext of control with DataGrid Environment:

```
    MyUserControl.DataContext =  Environment;
```